# Keeping the SSH fingerprint of an EC2 instance managed by an ASG

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, autoscaling

I have a server instance hosted on AWS EC2. The EC2 instance is managed through a Launch template that is used with an ASG (min:1 max:1 desired:1). It's a simple setup.

The AMI used for the Launch template is the instance own AMI, so it keeps the same data on the instance volume across restarts.

I need the SSH fingerprint of this instance to be kept across instance restarts. So that it won't bother my users in case of the ASG spawning a new instance.

I have an **S3 bucket** that I use to backup some configuration files, I tried using it to baskup the server SSH keys. And fetch then upon instance restart in the instance user data, without success.

Backup code:

```bash
zip ssh_keys.zip /etc/ssh/ssh_host* && aws s3 cp ssh_keys.zip s3://{{ backup_s3_bucket_name }}/config_files/server/ssh_keys.zip
```

User data to recover the keys:

```bash
aws s3 cp s3://${backup_s3_bucket_name}/config_files/server/ssh_keys.zip ssh_keys.zip && unzip -o ssh_keys.zip -d / && systemctl restart sshd
```

Comment: See [Setting Host Fingerprint on New EC2 Instances](https://serverfault.com/questions/736850/setting-host-fingerprint-on-new-ec2-instances).

Comment: Isn't it possible without having to create another instance of SSHd on a different port? Or is there a reason I can't use the standard 22 SSH port?

Comment: Stepping back, you mentioned that you wanted this SSH fingerprint to persist across instance restarts. That should already be the case, if by "restart" you mean a reboot. I guess that you mean the scenario in which the ASG terminates and replaces the instance. See [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/581367/amazon-ec2-instance-ssh-rsa-fingerprint) for other potential solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the link. That's quite interesting.
However, I finally found my solution. My simple user_data script which erases the `/etc/ssh/ssh_host*` with backuped versions stored on S3 was working. 


It's just that **the user_data is run after a few minutes one the instance has started**, so at first glance, you'll see that the SSH fingerprint has changed, and then after a fe minutes it'll connect just fine without host identification message.